# Hide CouponCode behind button tag, and display in model when Click on Button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

Need help with coding a Hide Coupon function using .Net MVC. I am looking to Hide a Coupon Code behind a button and code should appear in a Modal as soon as any one clicks on Button. I tried to look help on google but was unable to find a structure for the same.

Here is my Code for CouponPage

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
                <p>@Html.Action("StoreMenuPartial", "Shop")</p>
                <p>@Html.Action("CategoryMenuPartial", "Shop")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 text-left" style="padding:20px;">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="store">
                                <div class="col-md-2 offer">
                                    <p>@Html.Raw(item.Offer)</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Title)</strong>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" style="width:190px;" href=" @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OfferLink)" target="_blank">GET DEAL</a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <p>@Html.Raw(item.OfferDetails) </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                }
                </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
                <div class="well">
                    <p>ADS</p>
                </div>
                <div class="well">
                    <p>ADS</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my Coupn Model Class

```
public class Coupn
    {
        [Key]
        public int CoupnID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int StoreID { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Offer { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public string OfferDetails { get; set; }
        public string OfferLink { get; set; }
        public int CatID { get; set; }
        public string CatName { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string CouponCode { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("StoreID")]
        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Stores { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CatID")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

I am referring to

```
public string CouponCode { get; set; }
```

property to display Coupon, but it should also open in a Modal.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `partial view` with `jquery aja`x to achieve it.

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult ShowCouponCode(int coupnId)
        {
            MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();
            var model = context.Coupn.Find(coupnId);
            return PartialView("_CouponCode", model);
        }
```

### Update

In order to ensure that you jump to the url of the corresponding field after opening the modal, you can record it as an `attribute` on the corresponding button like data-offerlink.(Here i assume the property to store the url is OfferLink)

Coupon Page:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication_mvc.Models.Coupn>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@section Scripts{

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".showmodal").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var coupnId = $(this).attr("data-coupnId");
                var url = $(this).attr("data-offerlink");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Shop/ShowCouponCode",
                    data: { "coupnId": coupnId },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#partial').html(data);
                        window.open(url);
                    }
                })
            });

        });
    </script>

}
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            @*<p>@Html.Action("StoreMenuPartial", "Shop")</p>
                <p>@Html.Action("CategoryMenuPartial", "Shop")</p>*@
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 text-left" style="padding:20px;">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="store">
                            <div class="col-md-2 offer">
                                <p>@Html.Raw(item.Offer)</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Title)</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" style="width:190px;" href=" @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OfferLink)" target="_blank">GET DEAL</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <p>@Html.Raw(item.OfferDetails) </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg showmodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-coupnId="@item.CoupnID" data-offerlink="@item.OfferLink">Show CouponCode</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header ">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Coupon Code</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="partial">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <div class="well">
                <p>ADS</p>
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                <p>ADS</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PartialView which named _CouponCode.cshtml:

```
    @model WebApplication_mvc.Models.Coupn


    <script>
    $(".copyCode").click(function () {
        var copyText = $("#code");
        copyText.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        alert("You have copied the CouponCode!");
    })
</script>

<div class="modal-body">
    <label class="col-2 control-label">The CouponCode of @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.CoupnID)</label>
    <div class="col-4">
        <input type="text" id="code" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.CouponCode)" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CouponCode))
    {
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary copyCode">Copy Coupon Code</button>
    }
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Js in Coupon Page:

```
@section Scripts{

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".showmodal").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var coupnId = $(this).attr("data-coupnId");
                var url = $(this).attr("data-offerlink");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Shop/ShowCouponCode",
                    data: { "coupnId": coupnId },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#partial').html(data);
                        window.open(url);
                    }
                })
            }); 
        });
    </script>

}
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you friend, but I didn't get success, I even tried on new test projects but there's no response ,

Comment: Some thing is not working here for me, I followed above steps with new test project but Ajaxx call is simply not getting called. Also, please clarify in you jquery you mentioned $('#partial').html(data); , where does this ID appears in the complete line of Code.

Comment: `$('#partial').html(data)`  where the `id=partial` div is in the Coupon Page. If you use my code for a global search, you will find it in the `modal-body`  module.
I suggest you use F12 to debug js code, and then confirm what the error message is.

Comment: Great, Thank you for all your help, Now I know the missing link. Works as expected.

Comment: @Riyaz, if my post helps you ,please accept  it as the answer.

Comment: Yes I will for sure, just a small hitch, how can we redirect as well open the modal at the same time on a Click, can you suggest on this. I did try a few things like, adding <a> tag around the <button> tag, but not working for me. Any suggestions on this? If you notice the GET DEAL button does redirect to another page, so at the same time a modal should pop up. How can we achieve this?

Comment: @Riyaz, Do you mean that you want to open a new page by clicking on the button and display the modal on the new page?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, Click should open modal with the Coupon code as it is doing now, and simultaneously it should redirect to another url,

Comment: @Riyaz, you can just add this sentence  `window.open("/Controller/Action");`  after `$('#partial').html(data)`

Comment: My Coupon Model class has a property which stores url for specific websites, example: Title: Flat 50% Off , Coupon Code: FLATFLIP, URL:flipkart.com, Hence SHOW COUPON button click should redirect to the specific website url updated for specific COupons. Also, can you suggest me a function that will allow users to copy the Coupon Code from Modal by a click of button . Thank you again

Comment: @Riyaz, I have updated my post, there are detailed code here .

Comment: Appreciate all your help, this works great, All your help means a lot

Comment: kindly suggest on this. All is working great, say now I updated the routes from http://localhost:52859/shop/store/dominos TO http://localhost:52859/store/dominos. Why is that post updating routes Coupon Code does not appear in the Modal when click on Show Coupon button? Kindly suggest. Thank you

Comment: @Riyaz, if you changed the route, the url of ajax post method should also change like this:   `url:"/store/dominos",` , and if you change route by Route attribute, you also need to add this  `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`  in the RouteConfig.cs file like this : https://forums.asp.net/t/2154465.aspx?Asp+net+mvc+attribute+routing+produces+404+error+on+subsequent+requests

Comment: In the above code, not all will have a Coupon code. How can I show Copy Coupon code button only to ones that does consist the Coupon Code. How could this be achieved. Please suggest

Comment: @Riyaz, put the myModal module outside the loop, and put all the modal-body and modal-footer in the partial view, and add an if judgment outside the Copy Coupon Code button. If the CouponCode exists, display the button. And write the CopyCode click event in jquery to the partial view, I have updated the post. And if you have any other problems, I suggest you reopen a thread to ask, because there are already many comments here.

Comment: Thank you, made few changes on it, and is working as expected.Thank you again :D